# How to push to different branch - GitHub Desktop

Tags: git, github, branch

How can I download the project from one brunch, and then push my changes to a new branch using **GitHub Desktop**?

If after making changes I'm trying to switch to another branch I see an error message:
[image]

Comment: you should commit changes before switching to another branch

Comment: @AlexanIs there any way to remove my changes (overwrite by the content of any branch)? And what should be my actions after that - how can I grab content from brahch and push with changes to another branch?

Comment: commit to your current branch, then switch to another and merge from previous

Answer (score 0):

```
git stash - will save your changes then
git checkout branch_name - checkout other branch
git stash apply - will apply your saved changes
```

then
commit like you normally would